# Multiple $.getJSON requests return differently within promise

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, promise

I have following code:

```
var aReq = $.getJSON('/path/A'),
    bReq = $.getJSON('/path/B');

$.when(aReq, bReq).then(function(A, B) {
  console.log(A, B);
  // logs: [Array[5], "success", Object], [Array[20], "success", Object]
});
```

Why is this wrapped in a "jqXHR array"?

With a single `$.getJSON` this doesn't happen:

```
var aReq = $.getJSON('/path/A');
$.when(aReq).then(function(A) {
  console.log(A);
  // logs: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
  // just like I wanted it in the first version
});
```

Is there a way to accomplish that the first version works? Maybe I understood something wrong with promises/deferred objects.

FWIW: I am using jQuery version 1.7.1 in this case.

Comment: Did you try console.loggin those one at a time. ?

Comment: @adeneo No, those were seperate tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is well documented in the api as the intended behavior: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

If it wasn't returned in an array, how would it return different results for each passed in promise considering each passed in promise could have multiple arguments returned?

From the documentation:

> If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when and it is not a Deferred
>   or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any
>   doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately. The doneCallbacks
>   are passed the original argument. In this case any failCallbacks you
>   might set are never called since the Deferred is never rejected.
>
> In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to jQuery.when,
>   the method returns the Promise from a new "master" Deferred object
>   that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds it has been
>   passed. The method will resolve its master Deferred as soon as all the
>   Deferreds resolve, or reject the master Deferred as soon as one of the
>   Deferreds is rejected. If the master Deferred is resolved, it is
>   passed the resolved values of all the Deferreds that were passed to
>   jQuery.when. For example, when the Deferreds are jQuery.ajax()
>   requests, the arguments will be the jqXHR objects for the requests, in
>   the order they were given in the argument list.

Comment: Damn, I searched all over `$.then`. Thanks, now it makes sense